# Approval Form Sometimes Requires Double Click to Approve/Reject

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, infopath, approval-process

We have a SharePoint Designer WF that spawns an approval WF. The form for the approval is giving us several issues.

1. Occasionally users have to double click the approve or reject button. This confuses users who think they have completed the approval when they have not.
2. Sometimes the circular, spinning "marquee" does not show after the user clicks approve/reject and the page just hangs there on the form for a few seconds and then jumps forward. In combination with the issue above you can see users get confused and frustrated by this.

Does anyone have a suggestion for where I might even begin to troubleshoot this?

Additional Info:
We just witnessed a case where in OutLook a user attempted to open the form to approve and this window opened and fluttered in and out in what can only be described as a seizure. The form never opened.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue seems to be related tot he following SharePoint.SE question [Users cannot view approval form in sharepoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16352/users-cannot-view-approval-form-in-sharepoint) as we are also experiencing this issue. We have recreated the approval work flow and the error has gone away. Not ideal, but there seemed to be no other option.